# Image buffer in C

Tags: c, image-processing

I have an 128x128 image stored as a contigous array of 2048 bytes. Given pixel x,y, how can i retrieve the byte index + bit index of the pixel? This is a monochrome, binary image.

Comment: You are prolly gonna need the division and modulus operators.

Comment: @MartinJames, that's for converting back, in this case he has x,y, he just needs to multiply and add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code with a sample call that retreives the pixel value at position (33, 41).

```
#include <limits.h>

// Returns the char position and bit of pixel x, y.
void calc_pos(int x, int y, int width, int *char_no, int *bit_no) {
  *char_no = (x + y * width) / CHAR_BIT;
  *bit_no =  (x + y * width) % CHAR_BIT;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int char_no, bit_no;
    int x = 33, y = 41; // Sample position
    int pixel_value;   

    calc_pos(x, y, 128, &char_no, &bit_no);

    pixel_value = img[char_no] & (1 << bit_no);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Idx = Y * 128 + X

The general form for this is:

Idx = Y * ImageWidth + X

For 0 ≤ Y ≤ ImageHeight and 0 ≤ X ≤ ImageWidth

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your image is as follows:

0 1 2 3 ... 127

1

2

3

...

127

Every row of pixels has `width` amount pixels, so you have

`y * width` to give you the row.

You want to access an `x` value on that specific row, so then you have

`(y * width) + x` to give you an offset along that row.

But of course, each pixel is 8 bytes long (2 each for R, G, B, A) in your example, so you multiply by bpp (bits per pixel), so you have

`((y * width) + x) * bpp`.

This of course assumes that the image is formatted in the way you described. If the image is bottom up instead of top down, or only has RGB data, you would need to do a little extra math to get to the right pixel data.